# TF 2.0 create model-- 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following error when I execute the code below.

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

### source code

```
    inp = Input(shape=(TIME_STEPS, INPUT_DIM,))
    inp_time = Input(shape=(1,))
    print(tf.executing_eagerly())  # return True
    
    print(inp_time.numpy()) # error
    # inp_time=inp_time.eval()/ K.get_value()/ x.numpy()/ K.eval()
    x = ConvAtteShare(inp_time=inp_time.numpy(),kernel=(32,32),stride=(16,16),filter_num=3)(inp)
    x = Dense(kind_num,activation='softmax')(x)
    m = Model(inputs=[inp,inp_time], outputs=[x], name='convatte-test')
    print(m.summary())
```

### error

```
print(inp_time.numpy())

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

If I am correct, .Numpy is only supported in eager mode which I am supposed to be running on (see print(tf.executing_eagerly()) returns true)

Need help to figure out the error and where could have gone wrong.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Update your tensorflow package or if you cannot, try typing

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

at the beginning of your python script and execute.

Comment: i use tf2.0, default eager mode.

Comment: now, the question is: how to convert a symbolic tensor to a int?